# Connecting OBS-STUDIO to Nginx server

Tags: nginx, vlc, http-live-streaming

I have installed and started the Nginx server on Ubuntu 14.04. My objective is to stream a video (live) using HLS (HTTP live streaming). I followed this tutorial https://www.vultr.com/docs/setup-nginx-on-ubuntu-to-stream-live-hls-video, and it recommends using OBS-STUDIO. However, I don't know how to stream from the OBS-STUDIO to the Nginx and then view the stream from other machines (e.g. with VLC).

Comment: Hi There, Did you find the solution for this? Please let me know if you did?

Comment: Hi. In obs-studio, Choose the media that you want to stream first. Then go to Settings. Choose Stream tab. For streaming servers, choose Custom. Specify two things: 1. the URL (e.g. rtmp://192.168.2.1/) 2. Steamkey (e.g. livestream). Then start streaming. If you check your apache2 directory, you will see the HLS video segments being created. I assume you have already set up you nginx server. Let me know if it works out for you.

Comment: I was able to start streaming but VLC did not show any picture. I am using Win10. Please let me k now the steps if possible. I see only black screen on VLC when I enter network URL

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I am not sure about Win10. Did you restart the apache2 and nginx? If you want to know exactly what is happening, do  this. Before you open the network URL, Click on Tools->Messages in VLC. Change the verbosity to 2 (Debug). Then open the Network URL. Then check the debug window and see what is going on. Good luck. sorry for the late reply. :)

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Hey can you tell me what latency were you getting when you were live streaming obs-studio to VLC? I am getting a latency of 10-20 secs for RTMP. I know it depends upon lot of factors but I want to bring down this number. Just wanted to make sure if I am not missing any thing here. Making changes in settings should reduce the number?

Comment: I don't really remember about the latency. Besides, I am no longer using obs-studio with nginx server. I was just testing how different it is from using plain apache2 server that contains the video fragments. I remember it was not streaming that well though.

Comment: one last question, have you tried RTP or RTSP live streaming using obs-studio?

Comment: Nope. I didn't. One thing I remember is that obs-studio accepted only RTMP URL to stream. The /hls code in nginx was then getting the stream from rtmp url, fragmenting it, and then storing it in the apache server in real time. I would then fire up VLC in the client machine and specify the stream with HTTP (not rtmp or rtsp).It had jitters and non-smooth streaming. So I abandoned it. I hope that was useful.

Comment: did you try something else as well?What other options did you try? With less latency. I appreciate your help!!

Comment: I used apache2 only. I store the video segments there and use VLC as a client to stream. You are welcome.

Comment: what latency did you get for  apache2? I have seen a significant difference  when I used SMplayer. It reduced latency from 10 sec to 3secs.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add a media source for OBS.
2. Configure the self-defined media server on OBS, add a URL as follows:

> ```
> URL: rtmp://domain_name:1935/hlslive
> stream name: test
> ```

3. Build Nginx with nginx-rtmp-module ,install, and then config nginx.conf

> vim /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf

add or config the following module:

```
rtmp {

    server {

        listen 1935;  #listen port

        chunk_size 4096;


        application hlslive {  #rtmp push stream request path 
            live on;
            hls on;
            hls_path /usr/share/nginx/html/hlslive/test;
            hls_fragment 3s;
            hls_playlist_length 18s;
        }
    }
}
```

also config as a http server for hls m3u8 request:

```
http {
    ...

    server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root  /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }
}
```

run nginx

> nginx -c /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf

4. Click Begin Push Stream on OBS.
5. Input the following URL to view the live video.

> http://domain_name:8080/hlslive/test/test.m3u8